# Setting a cookie on a different domain?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain, csrf, cross-site

Is it possible to set a cookie on a different domain? If so, what would be the best way to go about doing it? So For example if I was on attackersite.com and wanted to set a cookie called 'name' with a value on victimsite.com

Thanks.

Comment: thanks didn't see that! ^

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that. Allowing something like this means a big security issue.

If you need to send data to a different domain you could try with a query string value.